# JavaScript RegEx- the | pipe is not checking the length

Tags: javascript, regex

I have 3 expressions that i am checking. like 3 phone number conditions. if any one matches, then pass.
when i write these individually, it works well.
but when i combine them, it does not check the length contraint.

I am using | to seperate out and the .match to do the comparision

```
var number_card = /^((4[38][0-9]{13}))|((6[0-9]{12}([0-9]{3})?))|((8[5-8][0-9]{14}))$/;
```

Comment: We're really gonna need to see the regex

Comment: I think we will need to see the regex. Maybe

Comment: The `|` pipe symbol is not a length checking operator. Neither does it combine multiple constraints to be all true.

Comment: how shud the regex be then, or what operator can i use to check if any phone number is correct

Answer (score 2):

Here's your regex in free-spacing form (in a Python raw string):

```py
number_card = re.compile(r"""
    # One from 3 global alternatives:
      ^                    # Either g1of3:
      (                    # $1: ...
        (4[38][0-9]{13})   # $2: ...
      )                    # End $1: ...
    | (                    # Or g2of3: $3: ...
        (                  # $4: ...
          6[0-9]{12}       #
          ([0-9]{3})?      # $5: Optional ...
        )                  # End $4: ...
      )                    # End $3: ...
    | (                    # Or g3of3: $6: ...
        (8[5-8][0-9]{14})  # $7: ...
      )                    # End $6: ...
      $                    # Anchor to end of line|string.
    """, re.VERBOSE)
```

As you can see, there are three global alternatives. The problem is that the `^` start-of-string anchor applies only to the first alternative and the `$` end-of-string anchor applies only to the third alternative. You need to encapsulate the three alternatives inside a group for the anchors to work correctly like so (once again in Python free-spacing mode):

```py
number_card = re.compile(r"""
    ^                      # Anchor to start of line|string.
    (?:                    # One ... from 3 alternatives.
      (                    # Either a1of3 $1: ...
        (4[38][0-9]{13})   # $2: ...
      )                    # End $1: ...
    | (                    # Or a2of3 $3: ...
        (                  # $4: ...
          6[0-9]{12}       #
          ([0-9]{3})?      # $5: Optional ...
        )                  # End $4: ...
      )                    # End $3: ...
    | (                    # Or a3of3 $6: ...
        (8[5-8][0-9]{14})  # $7: ...
      )                    # End $6: ...
    )                      # End one ... from 3 alternatives.
    $                      # Anchor to end of line|string.
    """, re.VERBOSE)
```

Here it is back in JavaScript RegExp literal syntax:

```js
var number_card = /^(?:((4[38][0-9]{13}))|((6[0-9]{12}([0-9]{3})?))|((8[5-8][0-9]{14})))$/;
```

Note that there are quite a few unnecessary groups in this pattern that can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Without your regular expression it's impossible to tell where the problem is. But you can visualize your regex yourself with [Regexper](http://www.regexper.com) and perhaps find a solution yourself.

Comment: the link correctly displays the conditions i wish to try, but i dont know if | is not the correct opperator